# How do I grab text from Selenium (Java)?

Tags: java, html, selenium

I am trying to grab the text $1.00 from the following HTML code (I have the xpath, so don't worry about that). For this purpose, we can say the xpath is //*[@id="price-string"]

```
<strong id="price-string">$1.00</strong>
```

I have tried using driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="price-string"]")) followed by .gettext(), .getAttribute("textContent"), .getAttribute("innerHTML");

All of them return null, which means they could not find it.

I saw this post here on stackexchange: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/30627/how-to-get-text-under-strong-tag-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java that might help. They say problem is, you cannot directly target/find text nodes with Selenium WebDriver, only regular element nodes. How would you be able to implement a fix in java? Thanks!

Comment: Would be nice if you can post more `HTML` content or the URL to investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code -

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
String word = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//strong[@id='price-string']")).getText();
System.out.println(word);
```

Note - if this is what you are looking for then please mark this as an answer.

Comment: Perfect! it works! Now one last follow up... System.out.println(price); prints out "$1.00" as expected :) but System.out.println("String Price -" + price + "-"); will not print anything. Any ideas on that? Otherwise, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Do a wait statement before extracting the value and then wait for page fully loaded

Try this:

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
String value = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//strong[@id='price-string']")).getText();
System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: Can you explain how this code differs *significantly* from that in the accepted answer, posted nearly 2 years ago?